# Pulseaudio high CPU usage

Tags: fedora, cpu-usage, pulse-audio, priority

Is it normal that the pulseaudio process has sometimes a CPU usage of ~40%, even without playing audio? The process seems to run in realtime-priority, is that the cause of the problem?

Update:
I deactivated the realtime-scheduling in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and set the nice-level to `0`. Unfortunately it seems to have no effect.

Update-2:
I've removed `icecast` and `darkice`, that i installed some days ago to setup an internet radio station, because i thought they could be part of the problem. Pulseaudio still uses a huge amount of cpu time, and it seems that i'm not the only one  with this problem. If you need more system specs, please ask me.

Some (related) information about the machine from the screenshot below:

> - Fedora 18
> - HP Elitebook 8460p
> - intel i5-2520M

[image: CPU screenshot]

Comment: Switch to Arch. Everything's fine now :)

Comment: Which terminal tool gives you such nice output with a graph?

Comment: @rolf htop ----

Comment: @EnigmaCurry thanks! I found that out in the meantime. Pretty cool. I also found out `atop` but it requires a service.

Comment: You may be processing an audio source or have an unintended audio loop across multiple audio monitors.  Try:
1) Determine how many sinks you have via: pactl list sinks
2) pactl set-sink-mute 0 1 
3) pactl set-sink-mute 1 1
4) pactl set-sink-mute 2 1
5) and so on...
Keep an eye on the CPU load for each of the above.  Use "0" instead of "1" as the last character to unmute.

Comment: If using `pavucontrol`, I found that setting `Profile: Off` in `Configuration` for all sinks reduced CPU usage to 0.0%.  Naturally this is only appropriate when audio is not required.

Comment: LOL "Switch to Arch"...as of today a search on DuckDuckGo of "pulseaudio high cpu" brings here as a first result, but to "PulseAudio High CPU Usage - Arch Linux" as second result...